# How to distribute and deploy a java desktop program? ClickOnce for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, clickonce

I have a Java program I made using Eclipse IDE. I can export it as a JAR file, and after manually installing the JRE on other computers, I can run it there.

I am now looking for something similar to ClickOnce in Visual Studio, where you can specify the .NET frameworks needed by your application, and just publish your program to a server. The application would then be downloaded from a webpage, automatically manage program versions, and let users know when a new update is available.

I found that Java Web Start was used for something like this, but it has been deprecated and continued as Open Web Start (https://openwebstart.com/). Is this something that can be integrated in Eclipse? What else could I use for distributing and deploying my program?

Thanks,

Comment: Oracle is focusing on the core functionality.  You might want to look into an app (with a jre)

Comment: This site is not for general guidance. Try a forums site such as JavaRanch.com.